# Spring Security + MVC - @Secured - Already declared global-method-security in *servlet.xml

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Hope someone could help me.

I am trying to configure Spring Security 3.1 with Spring MVC 3.0.8 but the annotated controllers does not get the access restricted by Spring.

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/Spring/applicationContext-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/Spring/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Sitemash -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <!-- <servlet-name>referencia</servlet-name> -->
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Spring Listeners -->

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/erroInterno.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>stc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>stc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

<!-- import the dataSource definition -->
<import resource="applicationContext-dataSource.xml"/>

<!-- Pacote base que sera scaneada por componentes annotados que serao auto-registrados como Spring beans.-->
<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.cielo.portalcontestacao" />

<!-- Ativa a detecao de annotations nas classes -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only! -->
<mvc:annotation-driven  />

<!-- Recursos utilizados nos imports das páginas -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/static/" cache-period="31556926"/>

<!-- Template para uso nos DAOs -->
<bean id="namedParameterJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="0-3" queue-capacity="0" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" keep-alive="300"/>
<task:annotation-driven executor="taskExecutor" />

<bean id="lobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler">
</bean>

<!-- Configuração de Locale -->
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="pt_BR" />
</bean>

<!-- Annotação para controle de transações na aplicação -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<!-- Indica qual o transaction manager a ser utilizado -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true"/>
</bean>

<!-- Mensagens do sistema --> 
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="basename" value="mensagens" />
</bean>

<bean name="stcProperties" class="br.com.cielo.portalcontestacao.service.utils.STCProperties"/>

<bean name="serviceInvoker" class="br.com.cielo.portalcontestacao.service.ServiceInvokerImpl"/>
</beans>
```

**applicationContext-security.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation=
    "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<http pattern="/static/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/" security="none"/>

<http auto-config='true' disable-url-rewriting="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/login" access="anonymous or fullyAuthenticated" />
    <form-login login-page="/pages/login"  />

    <session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
    </session-management>
</http>

<beans:bean id='userDetailsService'
    class="br.com.cielo.portalcontestacao.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl">
    <beans:property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"/>
    <beans:property name="namedParameterJdbcTemplate" ref="namedParameterJdbcTemplate"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id='stcAuthenticationProvider'
    class="br.com.cielo.portalcontestacao.security.AuthenticationProviderServiceImpl">
    <beans:property name="serviceInvoker" ref="serviceInvoker"/>
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager erase-credentials="true">
    <authentication-provider ref='stcAuthenticationProvider' />
</authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

**stc-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- DispatcherServlet application context for web tier. -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<!--context:annotation-config/-->
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

<mvc:view-controller path="/pages/login" view-name="login"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/pages/home" view-name="index"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/pages/acessonegado" view-name="acessoNegado"/>

<!-- Declara as Exceptions a serem tratadas pelo framework -->
<!--bean class="br.com.cielo.portalcontestacao.service.exceptions.GenericException">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.lang.Exception">dataAccessFailure</prop>
            <prop key="org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound">pageNotFound</prop>
            <prop key="org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
            <prop key="org.springframework.transaction.TransactionException">dataAccessFailure</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean-->

<!-- Declaracao dos Views Resolvers utilizados na aplicacao -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
   <property name="basename" value="views"/>
   <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="mensagens"/>
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
     <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
     <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />
 </bean>
</beans>
```

Here is some class that I want the access restricted by Spring Security:
*imports ommited*

**ImportacaoArquivo.java**

```
@Secured("ROLE_SCHEDULE")
@Controller
public class ImportacaoArquivo {

    @Secured("ROLE_SCHEDULE")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/pages/schedules", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public final ModelAndView exibirPageLinks(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        return new ModelAndView("arquivo");
    }
}
```

Comment: In your applicationContext.xml, I'm not seeing that you import applicationContext-security.xml

Comment: Hi Luciano, thank you for your comment. The applicationContext-security is imported in web.xml:

    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/Spring/applicationContext-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/Spring/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>

Answer (score 3):

`<security:global-method-security />` should be declared in the same context where beans you want to secure are declared.

Since your controller is declared (by `<context:component-scan />`) in the root context, `<security:global-method-security />` should be declared there as well.

Comment: Hi, axtavt! Thank you for the answer.

Although the components are scanned in application context, the controllers are managed by the dispatch servlet context. So the instruction to apply security restrictions should be at stc-servlet.xml.

Anyway, I tryed the config that you suggested, putting <security:global-method-security /> in applicationContext.xml with no success.

Do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

So, this is the information I've gathered from reading different sources:

- Your `<security:global-method-security />` has to be declared in **stc-servlet.xml**
- `<context:component-scan />` for your your controllers has to be declared in **stc-servlet.xml**. The scanning for the rest of your beans may remain in **applicationContext.xml**. This would work best if your controllers are contained inside one package and nothing else is there (for instance *br.com.cielo.portalcontestacao.controllers*).
- Also on **stc-servlet.xml** you need to define `<aop:config proxy-target-class="true" />`. This instructs Spring to use CGLib to advice methods and classes, and you need that because your controllers do not implement any interface.

Alternative solutions:

- Use regular *intercept-url* to define which endpoints have to be secure.
- Use `@Secured` annotation on your services instead of using it on the controllers.

Comment: Luciano, I moved both `<security:global-method-security/>` and `<context:component-scan base-package="br.com.cielo.portalcontestacao.web.controller"/>` to stc-servlet.xml and tryed `<aop:config proxy-target-class="true" />` and `<security:global-method-security proxy-target-class="true" />` with no success.

Answer (score 0):

delete 'final' keyword from the method in your **ImportacaoArquivo.java** file:

```
@Secured("ROLE_SCHEDULE")
@RequestMapping(value = "/pages/schedules", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView exibirPageLinks(final HttpServletRequest request) {
    return new ModelAndView("arquivo");
}
```